# Google realtime analytics API with Ruby

Tags: ruby, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use Google analytics realtime functionality but it doesn't seem to be working.  I saw a similar post and implemented the solution but it does not seem to work.  Here is my code

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'

# Update these to match your own apps credentials
service_account_email = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com' # Email of service account
key_file = '/path/to/key/privatekey.p12' # File containing your private key
key_secret = 'notasecret' # Password to unlock private key
profileID = '111111111' # Analytics profile ID.

# Get the Google API client
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => '[YOUR APPLICATION NAME]',
:application_version => '0.01')

# Load your credentials for the service account
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
:token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
:scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
:issuer => service_account_email,
:signing_key => key)

# Start the scheduler
SCHEDULER.every '1m', :first_in => 0 do

# Request a token for our service account
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

# Get the analytics API
analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3')

# Execute the query
visitCount = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.realtime.get, :parameters => {
'ids' => "ga:" + profileID,
'metrics' => "ga:activeVisitors",
})

# Update the dashboard
send_event('cur_visitors', { current: visitCount.data.rows[0][0] })
end
```

However I get the error

```
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass
```

for the second last line.  I know that the API does work for non-realtime functionality so I do not think there is any problem with authorization.  Can anyone suggest why this could be happening?

Comment: No, but for starters you could check to see if it's `visitCount.data.rows` that's `nil` or whether it's `visitCount.data.rows[0]` that's nil.

Comment: its visitCount.data.rows[0] that is nil.  Sorry, probably should have included that.